# Can't log user in on SOAP API

Tags: api, c#, soap, .net

I have added the IP to SalesForce and tried appending the security token to the password and checked that the user's profile has API enabled but still no luck.

The user account can log in fine using a browser.

Can someone please explain what settings a user needs to be able to log in through the API? Or how to debug this further. I can see the failed login attempts on the web interface.

This is my code:

```
        var header = new SalesForceAPI.LoginScopeHeader { organizationId = "00D40000000XXXX" };
        var service = new SalesForceAPI.SoapClient();
        var result = service.login(header, "XXXX@XXX.com", "XXXX" );
```

The exception I get is: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

What is a self service user?

Comment: What reason does the failed login attempt in the user's login history specify on the web interface?

Comment: Did you append the security token to the password?

Comment: I think you have all the pieces you need. Have you tried regenerating the security token?

Comment: The Website notes the login attempt with status "Invalid Login". I regenerated the security token to get it in the first place but it shouldn't be required because the service calls are coming from a known IP. I wondered if there could be a weird profile think I was missing or that I needed to pass in the LoginScopeHeader

Comment: Once you've whitelisted the IP for a profile adding the security token will cause an invalid login.  Have you tried logging in with just the password?  Or after removing the IP restriction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I imported the Partner v26 WSDL into a Visual Studio 2012 console application **as a Web Service Reference** (not a WCF service reference).

Then with a bit of painful cutting and pasting from the PDF I brought the C# example code in from the SOAP API developers guide pg 27 referenced by Jordan in his answer. It looks like their example is designed for use with the Enterprise WSDL as it has a Contact object in the querySample() method. So I hacked that section out to get it compiling.

I named the Web reference "SforceService", so the only other change I needed to make was to change the `using Walkthrough.sforce;` to `using ConsoleApplication1.SforceService;`.

I was able to run the sample code and establish a Salesforce session with a username and password (no security token as the IP had been trusted in the org).

Do you want me to try and zip up the console application project and share a link?

---

```
string username = "XXX@YYY.com";
string password = "password";
// Create a service object
SforceService binding = new SforceService();
// Timeout after a minute
binding.Timeout = 60000;
// Try logging in
LoginResult lr;
try
{
    lr = binding.login(username, password);
}
// ApiFault is a proxy stub generated from the WSDL contract when
// the web service was imported
catch (SoapException e)
{
    // Write the fault code to the console
    Console.WriteLine(e.Code);
    // Write the fault message to the console
    Console.WriteLine("An unexpected error has occurred: " + e.Message);
    // Write the stack trace to the console
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    // Return False to indicate that the login was not successful
    return false;
}
// Check if the password has expired
if (lr.passwordExpired)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error has occurred. Your password has expired.");
    return false;
}
/** Once the client application has logged in successfully, it will use
* the results of the login call to reset the endpoint of the service
* to the virtual server instance that is servicing your organization
*/
// Save old authentication end point URL
String authEndPoint = binding.Url;
// Set returned service endpoint URL
binding.Url = lr.serverUrl;
/** The sample client application now has an instance of the SforceService
 * that is pointing to the correct endpoint. Next, the sample client
 * application sets a persistent SOAP header (to be included on all
 * subsequent calls that are made with SforceService) that contains the
 * valid sessionId for our login credentials. To do this, the sample
 * client application creates a new SessionHeader object and persist it to
 * the SforceService. Add the session ID returned from the login to the
 * session header
 */
binding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = lr.sessionId;
```

Note that the [LoginScopeHeader](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_loginscopeheader.htm) is not required. According to the linked documentation it:

> Specifies your organization ID so that you can authenticate
>   Self-Service users for your organization using the existing login().

Comment: Thank you very much but I'm up and running now. Out of interest does your login method take 2 or 3 params? I'm using enterprise WSDL

Comment: @Max Just two when using the partner WSDL.

Comment: This comment made me realize why I had such issues with it; WCF has a different, more annoying format.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Wireshark` or some other low-level network request program to debug your requests if you don't have an IDE to examine your requests. You should be able to get started and verify your on the right track using simple `CURL` requests from the command line.

The [SOAP API developers guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/apex_api.pdf) has easy quick start examples to get you going.

See page 27, it has C# example code, copy and paste it, and confirm it works.

Comment: The documentation seems completely inaccurate. For example there is no mention of creating a login scope header which is in the WSDL.

Comment: Where did you get the reference to the `login scope header` if it's not mentioned than you probably don't need it, if it is mentioned and not explained that's not good!

Comment: Also, you would recommend sending SOAP messages using CURL??

Comment: I said in my comment, it's in the WSDL.

Comment: not necessarily no, although it's certainly possible, I'd probably recommend [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org)

Comment: Ah I see, but if it's not necessarily mentioned in the documentation that you need to assign it in the header of your request than you probably don't need it. I'm not an expert on the shape of SOAP specifications

Comment: The code samples do not match up with the proxies that Visual Studio generates, preventing those code samples from being run.

Comment: I'm not at my windows machine right now maybe someone else could confirm the stub generated based from the current version of wsdl api in salesforce and _visual studio 2012_?

Comment: You were right in that no LogicScopeHeader is required. That is used for self-service users.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of effort was put into the answers and comments given but none succinctly explain the problem and the solution.

LoginScopeHeader is only required for self-service users.

The following code is all that is required to login using Visual Studio generated proxies from the Enterprise WSDL.

```
    var service = new SalesForceAPI.SoapClient();
    var result = service.login(null, "XXXX@XXX.com", "XXXX" );
```

Unlike the documentation, my service will not compile without three arguments for the login method.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Login History for any issues.
Also try to write some simple script which will check your credentials.

Example test script in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Usage $: PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME=0 ./sf-test-login.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use lib 'lib';
use lib $ENV{HOME}.'/lib/perl5';
use REST::Client;
use JSON;
# use Data::Dump qw(dump);

##### Salesforce setup/login
my $grant_type = "password";
my $client_id = "CHANGE_THIS";
my $client_secret = "CHANGE_THIS";
my $username = "CHANGE_THIS";
my $password = "CHANGE_THIS";

my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;
my $client = REST::Client->new();

$client->setHost('https://emea.salesforce.com');
$client->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

my $login_body = "grant_type=$grant_type&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&username=$username&password=$password";

$client->POST('/services/oauth2/token', $login_body);
my $result = $client->responseContent();
my $json_result = $json->decode( $result );

print "Token is ", $json_result->{"access_token"}, $/;
```

See:

- [Understanding the Username-Password OAuth Authentication Flow](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your password does not have any special characters in it that are causing problems.  This was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Removing special characters** from the password works. After updating your password, you must also reset and update your `SECURITY_TOKEN`.